# Coping folder structure recursively but excluding newest file at lowest level

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will recursively search through subfolders/files and copy them to a new location while retaining structure.  I have achieved this below but want to also remove the newest file in each lowest sub directory.

Folder Structure:

C:\engines\analytics1\pa.kr
C:\engines\analytics1\pa419.kdb
C:\engines\analytics1\pa420.kdb
C:\engines\analytics1\pa421.kdb (newest file)
C:\engines\analytics2\pb.kr
C:\engines\analytics2\pb240.kdb
C:\engines\analytics2\pb241.kdb (newest file)

My need is to exclude `pa421.kdb` & `pb241.kdb` files and recursively copy everything else.  I have tried this many ways with nested `Get-ChildItem` method and descending creation time with `-Skip 1` logic, but could not get it to work.

```
if ($env:COMPUTERNAME.Contains("Test")) {
    $root_path = "C:"
    $backup_folder = "Appian\Backup"
}

$date = Get-Date -Format d.MMMM.yyyy.HH.mm.ss

New-PSDrive -Name "Backup" -PSProvider Filesystem -Root
$root_path\$backup_folder

$source1 = $root_path + "\engines"

$destination = "backup:\$date"
$path = Test-Path $destination

if ($path -eq $true) {
    #write-Host "Directory Already exists"
    Remove-PSDrive "Backup"#  -Force
} elseif ($path -eq $false) {
    cd backup:\
    mkdir $date

    Get-ChildItem $source1 -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($source1, $destination + "\engines") -Force
    }

    #$backup_log = Dir -Recurse $destination | Out-File "$destination\backup_log.txt"
}
```

Comment: Is your folder hierarchy shallow (i.e. just the immediate subfolders of `C:\engines`)? Or is the hierarchy deeper?

Comment: The hierarchy is deeper.  Parent Folder - engines, subfolder - analytics, subfolder - gw1, file - pb240.kdb.

Comment: And the files you want excluded are on different hierarchy levels, or always in the immediate subfolders of `C:\engines`?

Comment: The files I want excluded are on the same level as the rest of the files and always in the immediate subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a list of the files you want excluded:

```
$exclude = Get-ChildItem C:\engines\*\*.kdb | Group-Object Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object -Desc | Select-Object -First 1 -Expand FullName
}
```

Then recurse into `C:\engines`, exclude those files from the result list, and copy the rest:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\engines -Recurse -File | Where-Object {
    $exclude -notcontains $_.FullName
} | Copy-Item -Destination { $_.FullName -replace '^C:', $destination }
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar!  So caught up in making a one liner, didn't think to build exclusions.  Works great!